# dismax feat. stopwords , synonyms etc

Tags: lucene, solr, stop-words

Does dismax support all the features like the standard requestHandler ? stopwords ? synonymes ? stemming ? did you hear about "edismax" ?

I'm using Solr1.4

For my first tests of the stopwords , it doesn't work .. well i think so..

I configured my DisMax to match all terms if count terms=[1,2]

> Example  ( in french )
>
> - un tshirt (means : a tshirt , supposed to search only "tshirt" right even if my mm =2 )
>
>   - no results with dismax ( it's , looking for two terms ) : its dismax "un" word and "tshirt" word
>   - results found with standard query : seek only "tshirt" word .

thank you in advance for help:)

Comment: What does your stopwords file look like?  Does your fieldtype actually use the StopFilterFactory?  Perhaps you could post some relevant parts of your schema.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Ha thanks Aaron !
You are right not all my fieldTypes were using StopFilterFactory , the "string" type was set by default , without any analyzer ;)

This is how i added the analyzer .

```
<fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.LowerCaseTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"   ignoreCase="true"   words="french_stop.txt"  enablePositionIncrements="true" /> 
  </analyzer>
```

Now it's seems to be working .

Have a nice day ;)